# no "auto-generate release notes" button on github enterprise?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

i'm trying to setup a new gitHub enterprise repo and looking at using "releases". i wanted to try the auto generate release notes feature but I don't have the button that is shown here...

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/automatically-generated-release-notes

is this a problem with my version of github enterprise server (3.3.6), github enterprise server in general or something else i'm not doing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is available from 3.4 release onwards.
[https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/automatically-generated-release-notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNwbE.png)

Comment: thanks. must be something else causing it to fail then i guess.